# Call by name parametrized tests in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

In rails project I have the following test:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each do |i|
  test "mypow2 #{i}" do
    assert mypow2(i) == i*i
  end
end
```

if the test is not parametrized I can run it by:

```
rails test path/to/test --name=test_mypow2
```

so that I can run this single test.

Now that my test is parametrized, is there a way to run only those 5 tests, without knowing the values of the parameters.

Maybe something like:

```
rails test path/to/test --name=test_mypow2*
```

Note that this example is very simplified, my test data is quite complicated, and it is extremely inconvenient to put the values of the parameters in the test name, even though I know them.

Comment: I would take a look at FactoryBot and use sequences within your test. That way you don't need to worry about passing params into the test https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences

Comment: I took a look at FactoryBot. But I don't want to have a single test and loop within the test, I want these to appear as different tests. E.g. when the test fails for parameter "1" I want to know that right away(reported as ""mypow2 1" failed.